# ClassCastException when setting an animation

Tags: android, android-animation, classcastexception

I am getting this error in my developer docs and I am not sure why. I tested it on a few of my phones here and didnt have a problem.

```
private Animation slideLeftIn;
private Animation slideLeftOut;
private Animation slideRightIn;
private Animation slideRightOut;

              private void swipeInit() {

                    viewFlipper = (ecm2.android.ContentViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.statusFlipper);
                    slideLeftIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left_in);
// line 2366        slideLeftOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left_out); //error
                    slideRightIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_right_in);
                    slideRightOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_right_out);
}
```

log error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ecm2.android/ecm2.android.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ViewFlipper
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1833)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1854)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1041)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4333)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ViewFlipper
at ecm2.android.MainActivity.swipeInit(MainActivity.java:2366)
at ecm2.android.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:837)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1797)
```

the log says its at line 2366 which is setting one of the animations but it does the one fine before that so I am not sure the problem here

animation xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-100%p" android:duration="300"/>
```

this all started when I changed over to a custom viewflipper to get around an android bug. I dont really do anything in it except try to catch an exception in the `onDetachedFromWindow` it does everything it normally would since I call super in everything I use

EDIT:

ContentViewFlipper class

```
public class ContentViewFlipper extends ViewFlipper {
//class is used to try to prevent force closes on certain phone where the onDetachFromWindow would be 
//called when its not suppose to, this is an android bug

public ContentViewFlipper(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ContentViewFlipper( Context context, AttributeSet attrs ) {
      super( context, attrs );
   }

@Override
protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
      try {
         super.onDetachedFromWindow();
      }
      catch( Exception e ) {
          stopFlipping();
      }
   }
}
```

Declaration of viewFlipper

```
private ContentViewFlipper viewFlipper;
```

XML

```
<ecm2.android.ContentViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/statusFlipper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/incLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvIncidents"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:divider="@drawable/divider"
            android:dividerHeight="2dip"
            android:visibility="visible" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/statusLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginBottom="40dp">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvStatus"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@drawable/divider"
            android:dividerHeight="2dip"
            android:visibility="visible" android:layout_marginTop="50dp">
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dlLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginBottom="40dp">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvDistList"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@drawable/divider"
            android:dividerHeight="2dip"
            android:visibility="visible" android:layout_marginTop="50dp">
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/emNotesLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginBottom="40dp">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvEmNotes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="50dp">
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/stCalenLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginBottom="40dp">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvStCalendar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="50dp">
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

</ecm2.android.ContentViewFlipper>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing there might be a bit of confusion with the line number and that your object viewFlipper is defined as ViewFlipper viewFlipper, which could an issue when you cast it from ecm2.android.ContentViewFlipper if that isn't a decendent.

Comment: nope `viewFilpper` is a form of `ContentViewFlipper` and my XML with the ViewFlipper refrences that class also

Comment: damn was hoping it might be that easy, what happens if you change the animation to R.anim.slide_left_in?

Comment: well I dont know I cant reproduce the problem, as it is its working fine on my devices.

Comment: oh this is an error report from a device that got the app from the market?

Comment: yes it is. but what seems weird to me is that the log refrences the normal ViewFlipper class and not mine in the error `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ViewFlipper`

Answer (score 0):

As the exception is saying that the error occurred casting `android.widget.ViewFlipper`, I'm pretty sure that either side of the `viewFlipper = ...` line has the wrong type.

Either the `viewFlipper` variable is an `android.widget.ViewFlipper` and the control from the layout is an `ecm2.android.ContentViewFlipper` and can't be cast to `android.widget.ViewFlipper`, or the control in the layout is an `android.widget.ViewFlipper` which can't be cast to `ecm2.android.ContentViewFlipper`.

On which line does the error really occur when you single-step through your code in debug mode after setting a breakpoint to the `viewFlipper = ...` line?

Comment: like i said I cannot reproduce the problem, this is an error from my developer console so I do not know what exact line it is on I am only going by what the log shows. I will edit to show how my view flipper is declared